# Почему не срабатывает SQL запрос C# SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Использую SQLite совместно с C#

Имею код,записывающий данные из базы данных в Combobox.
Почему в первом случае - Query = "`SELECT * FROM Clients;`" данные записываются в Combobox,а во втором - нет Query = "`SELECT * FROM Stuff;`"

```
SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
try
{
    sqliteCon.Open();//Открываем соединение с бд
    string Query ="SELECT * FROM Clients;" ;//Создаем наш запрос SQL и помещаем его в переменную Query
    SQLiteCommand CreateCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);

    SQLiteDataReader dr = CreateCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        string name = dr.GetString(1);
        ClientsCombobox.Items.Add(name);
    }

    Query = "SELECT * FROM Stuff Where Post='Доктор';";//Создаем наш запрос SQL и помещаем его в переменную Query
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        string name = dr.GetString(1);
        ClientsCombobox.Items.Add(name);
    }

    sqliteCon.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Exсeption'ов не выдает...

**Решение:**

```
Query = "SELECT * FROM Stuff Where Post='Доктор';";//Создаем наш запрос SQL и помещаем его в переменную Query
SQLiteCommand CreateCommand2 = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqliteCon);
dr = CreateCommand2.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    string name = dr.GetString(1);
    DoctorsCombobox.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы же ничего не делаете с переменной Query после присваивания ей значения второго запроса, соответственно, ридер пуст и читать из него нечего

З.Ы. это уже не по теме, однако же кто вас учил так писать код? Плюньте ему в лицо

Comment: Если только лежа плюнуть :)

Comment: Рационально вводить новую переменную класса SQLiteCommand?

Comment: Можете немного подсказать, как можно было бы написать более правильно?

Comment: @Sergey_Yysmaa как написать "более правильно" - это тема, требующая отдельного обсуждения. Если вкратце - ни в коем случае не смешивать бизнес-логику, логику работы с бд и code-behind, не хардкодить запросы и особенно параметры, обрабатывать конкретные исключения